# Compilar informações na mesma linha

Tags: r, tidyverse

Preciso de ajuda para compilar em uma mesma linha informações contidas em linha distintas. Segue exemplo de df:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(
  Name = c("A", "A", "B", "B"),
  Week = c(100, NA, 200, NA),
  Weekend = c(NA, 2000, NA, 1500)
  )
```

O resultado que preciso ficaria neste formato:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É possível obter o resultado pretendido com o código abaixo, que agrupa os resultados por `Name` calcula o valor máximo das colunas `Week` e `Weekend`:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  summarise(Week = max(Week, na.rm = TRUE), 
            Weekend = max(Weekend, na.rm = TRUE))
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  Name   Week Weekend
  <chr> <dbl>   <dbl>
1 A       100    2000
2 B       200    1500
```

O mesmo resultado seria obtido com praticamente qualquer outra estatística como `min`, `median`, `mean` etc.

Problemas poderão surgir caso os dados possuam outro formato, como mais de uma observação não `NA` por grupo e por coluna.

Comment: Muito obrigado Marcus!